# Spring boot: JSON parameter starting with special character

Tags: java, json, rest, spring-boot

I'm using Spring Boot for a REST Server, but I would like to have some of the parameter of the json string using special character as bellow (_id, $oid):

```
 "data": [
    {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "122121b1212v2aa99898ee"
      },
```

Is this possible?
When defining the Class which has the elements I'm not able to define variables using this special characters...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`@JsonProperty`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonProperty.html) annotation in the class you map this JSON to. Something like:

```
public class Id {
    @JsonProperty("$oid")
    private String oid;

    public String getOid() {
        return oid;
    }

    public void setOid(String oid) {
        this.oid = oid;
    }
}
```

And:

```
public class Data {
    @JsonProperty("_id")
    private Id id;

    public Id getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Id id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this is implicit with Spring Boot as it uses Jackson by default to marshal/unmarshal JSON.

Comment: Cool! I didn't know about this annotation.
Thanks Szymon!

Comment: I'm glad I could help you :)